# Hacklang - Why are protected members invariant?

Tags: casting, covariance, hacklang

### The public member case

With the carte blanche access the calling scope has to them, it's no surprise that public members are invariant:

```
<?hh // strict
class Foo<+T> {
  public function __construct(
    public T $v
  ) {}
}
class ViolateType {
  public static function violate(Foo<int> $foo): void {
    self::cast_and_set($foo);
    echo $foo->v + 1; // string + integer
  }
  public static function cast_and_set(Foo<arraykey> $foo): void {
    $foo->v = "Poof! The integer `violate()` expects is now a string.";
  }
}
// call ViolateType::foo(new Foo(1)); and watch the fireworks
```

The problem here is that **both** `violate` and `cast_and_set` can read and modify the same value (`Foo->v`) with different expectations of its type.

This problem, however, doesn't seem to exist for protected members.

### Attempt to create a violation for protected members

Since the only distinction between `private` and `protected` is visibility to descendants, let's take a class (`ImplCov`) that, outside of some number of protected members, is otherwise validly covariant on a type, and extend it into a class (`ImplInv`) invariant on that type. Notably, being invariant on `T` allows me to expose a public setter — `violate(T $v): T` — where I'll try to break types.

```
<?hh // strict
// helper class hierarchy
class Base {}
class Derived extends Base {}

class ImplCov<+T> {
  public function __construct(
    protected T $v
  ) {}
}
class ImplInv<T> extends ImplCov<T> {
  public function violate(T $v): T {
    // Try to break types here
  }
}
```

With an instance of `ImplInv<Derived>`, I'm compelled to cast to an `ImplCov<Derived>`, then leverage covariance to cast to an `ImplCov<Base>`. It like the most dangerous thing to do, with all three types referring to the same object. Let's inspect the relationships between each type:

1. `ImplInv<Derived>` and `ImplCov<Base>`: The violation in the public member case occured when the property was changed to a supertype (int->arraykey) or disjoint type with a common supertype (int->string). However, because `ImplCov<Base>` is covariant on `T`, there cannot exist methods that can be passed a `Base` instance and make `v` a true `Base`. `ImplCov`'s methods cannot spawn a `new Base()` either and assign it to `v` because it doesn't know the eventual type of `T`.<sup>1</sup>

   Meanwhile, because casting `ImplCov<Derived> --> ImplCov<Base> --> ...` can only cause it to be less derived, `ImplInv::violate(T)` is guaranteed to at worst set `v` to a subtype of the eventual `ImplCov`'s `T`, guaranteeing a valid cast to that eventual `T`. The Derived of `ImplInv<Derived>` can't be cast, so once parameterized, that type is set in stone.
2. `ImplInv<Derived>` and `ImplCov<Derived>`: these can coexist by merit of `T` being the same between them, the cast being only of the outermost type.
3. `ImplCov<Derived>` and `ImplCov<Base>`: these can coexist by the assumption that `ImplCov` is validly covariant. The `protected` visibility of `v` is indistinguishable from `private`, since they are the same class.

All of this seems to point to protected visibility being kosher for covariant types. Am I missing something?

<sup>1. We can actually spawn `new Base()` by introducing the `super` constraint: `ImplCov<T super Base>`, but this is even weaker, since by definition `ImplInv` has to parameterize `ImplCov` in the `extends` statement with a supertype, making `ImplInv`'s operations with `v` safe. Plus, `ImplCov` can't assume anything about the members of `T`.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a subclass can modify a `protected` member of *any* object of that class, not just `$this`. So this slight modification of your example above uses a `protected` member to similarly break the type system -- all we have to do is make `ViolateType` a subclass of `Foo` (and it doesn't matter what we set `T` to, or if we make `ViolateType` generic or whatever).

```
<?hh // strict

class Foo<+T> {
    public function __construct(
        /* HH_IGNORE_ERROR[4120] */
        protected T $v
    ) {}
}

class ViolateType extends Foo<void> {
    public static function violate(Foo<int> $foo): void {
        self::cast_and_set($foo);
        echo $foo->v + 1; // string + integer
    }

    public static function cast_and_set(Foo<arraykey> $foo): void {
        $foo->v = "Poof! The integer `violate()` expects is now a string.";
    }
}
```

This passes the typechecker with only the one error suppression for the protected member -- so allowing protected members to be covariant would break the type system.